# Open Tizen Remote Web Inspector from command line

Tags: tizen, web-inspector, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I'm about to take over maintaining a Tizen 2017 js application, and am new to the platform. As far as I know, the application has been developed outside of the official Tizen IDE by taking the skeleton of a basic project, and doing the rest with normal web development toolchains. As such, the application can be installed and opened using the `tizen` CLI command, but it doesn't seem to be possible to install and inspect using the IDE (eg. "Run as" / "Debug as" fail) for whatever reason.

Is it possible to launch the [Remote web inspector](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/web-inspector/) from the command line?

Answer (score 11):

It took forever to figure this out but you can tell the TV to open a debugging port and then use sdb forward it to your local machine without the Tizen Studio IDE.

Assuming sdb is connected to the TV you can use the following

`sdb shell 0 debug SomePackage.Identifier`

then take the port returned there and forward it

`sdb forward tcp:45087 tcp:45087`

From there you can find your inspectable application at `chrome://inspect/devices#devices`

Comment: You need to use the correct local port which you'll get with `sdb devices` (default is 26102). My working command: `sdb forward tcp:26102 tcp:#remotePortNumber`. In order to inspect the device, i had to add `localhost:26101` to the list of network targets in `chrome://inspect/devices#devices`

Comment: I just needed to run `sdb shell 0 debug SomePackage.Identifier` which resulted in ... `successfully launched pid = 1257 with debug 1 port: 48105` and then I manually configured a new device using the port 48105 in chrome://inspect#devices without any need to forward any ports. However ecah time I run this a different port number is used, which means editing the configured port each time

Comment: Perhaps worth noting, in the example `SomePackage.Identifier`... Find it here:
`<tizen:application id="SomePackage.Identifier" package="Identifier" required_version="2.3"/>`

Answer (score 4):

#### Chrome Dev Tools

Prerequisites

- Chrome browser
- Samsung Development Bridge
- Command Line Tool

Actions:

0. Open Command Line Tool (Terminal/Command Prompt/Power Shell/Git Bash/ whatever you like)
1. `sdb connect 192.168.0.123` // Samsung TV IP Address
2. `sdb devices` and check that your device is present
3. Close the Telenor Stream app on your Samsung device by long pressing the back button on your samsung remote.
4. Open the app from command line `sdb shell 0 debug SomePackage.Identifier` should give this answer `... successfully launched pid = 15900 with debug 1 port: 37846`
5. Use port from answer `sdb forward tcp:37846 tcp:37846`
6. In Open Chrome and paste `chrome://inspect/#devices` in address bar
7. Check `Discover network targets` click `Configre` and add `localhost:37846`
8. Be sure that app is open on your Samsung and it will show up as a `Remote Target`
9. When redeploying app repeat step 3 - 7

#### Chii Debugger

Prerequisites

- Node
- Chii - https://github.com/liriliri/chii
- Command Line Tool

Actions

0. Open Command Line Tool (Terminal/Command Prompt/Power Shell/Git Bash)
1. Start Chii with command `chii start -p 8080`
2. Add `<script src="http://{your-computers-local-ip-address}:8080/target.js"></script>` to index.html
3. Deploy app to Samsung TV and start the app
4. Open browser and paste `http://localhost:8080/` in address bar
5. Click `Inspect`

Be sure that you have your Chii server runnig if script tag is present in index.html.

Comment/Remove Chii script if you don't use the chii debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answers here for posterity as I have been struggling with this today.

To launch the Chrome DevTools window correctly and automatically the following sequence is needed.

1. To kill any running instances of your app on the TV run `sdb shell 0 was_kill SomePackage.Identifier`
2. To start your app in debug mode on TV run `sdb shell 0 debug SomePackage.Identifier`
3. Read the port number from output (see python script below), let's assume it was `... successfully launched pid = 15900 with debug 1 port: 37846`
4. Remove any forwarded port configurations `sdb forward --remove tcp:37846`
5. Create new port forwarding `sdb forward tcp:37846 tcp:37846`
6. Find the correct url for the devtools window by parsing the JSON returned by `http://localhost:37846/json`, (key of interest is `json[0].devtoolsFrontendUrl`)
7. launch Chrome with `http://localhost:37846/{devtoolsFrontendUrl}`

I wrote a small Python script that I run to start my debugging session, this does it all and opens a chrome window for me to debug. Just like Tizen Studio.

`python debug_on_tv.py --appid SomePackage.Identifier --chrome "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import argparse # Command-line argument parser
import subprocess
import requests, json
import tempfile

def parseArguments():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

  parser.add_argument("--appid", help="The identifier of the tizen app",
                                 type=str)

  parser.add_argument("--chrome", help="path to chrome executable",
                                   type=str)

  return parser.parse_args()

##
## Note: reverse engineer the shell 0 commands from 
##       https://github.com/Samsung/Wits/blob/c18cf03eced66aa66c3603c94fccf4c14d193f00/lib/appLaunchHelper.js
def runMain():
  try:
    # Construct the argument parser for the commandline
    args = parseArguments()


    # Force a UTF8 environment for the subprocess so that files with non-ascii characters are read correctly
    # for this to work we must not use the universal line endings parameter
    my_env = os.environ
    my_env['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8'

    # Start by killing any processes already running
    prog_args = ['sdb']
    prog_args.append('shell')
    prog_args.append('0')
    prog_args.append('was_kill')
    prog_args.append(args.appid)
    subprocess.run(prog_args)


    # Start the app in debug mode
    prog_args = ['sdb']
    prog_args.append('shell')
    prog_args.append('0')
    prog_args.append('debug')
    prog_args.append(args.appid)
    ret = subprocess.Popen(prog_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, env=my_env)
    debugport = 0
    try:
      while True:
        try:
          line = ret.stdout.readline()
          if not line:
            break
          line = line.strip()

          # Searching for >>  ... successfully launched pid = 10422 with debug 1 port: 34187
          if 'with debug 1 port' in line:
            debugport = line[line.rfind(':')+1:].strip()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
          continue # Ignore all unicode errors, don't care!

      # Ensure that the return code was ok before continuing
      # Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute. Otherwise, returns None.
      retcode = ret.poll()
      while retcode is None:
        retcode = ret.poll()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      ret.terminate()
      raise


    # Got the debug port, kill any existing connections on this port before establishing a new one
    prog_args = ['sdb']
    prog_args.append('forward')
    prog_args.append('--remove')
    prog_args.append('tcp:{0}'.format(debugport))
    subprocess.run(prog_args)

    # Got the Debug port, now forward it
    prog_args = ['sdb']
    prog_args.append('forward')
    prog_args.append('tcp:{0}'.format(debugport))
    prog_args.append('tcp:{0}'.format(debugport))
    subprocess.run(prog_args)

    # Extract the complete debug path from the remote view
    # Idea from: https://github.com/Samsung/webIDE-common-tizentv/blob/dev/lib/appLauncher.js#L141C42-L141C47
    responseJson = json.loads(requests.get('http://localhost:{0}/json'.format(debugport)).text)
    devUrl = responseJson[0]['devtoolsFrontendUrl']

    # Start chrome, 
    # see cmd line params: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/main/src/flags.ts
    prog_args = [args.chrome]
    prog_args.append('--new-window')
    prog_args.append('--no-first-run')
    prog_args.append('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    prog_args.append('--hide-crash-restore-bubble')
    prog_args.append('--activate-on-launch')
    prog_args.append('--no-default-browser-check')
    prog_args.append('--allow-file-access-from-files')
    prog_args.append('--disable-web-security')  # This is critical, otherwise we cannot do unsecure CORS
    prog_args.append('--disable-features=Translate,OptimizationHints,MediaRouter')
    prog_args.append('--disable-extensions')
    prog_args.append('--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages')
    prog_args.append('--disable-background-networking')
    prog_args.append('--disable-component-update')
    prog_args.append('--disable-client-side-phishing-detection')
    prog_args.append('--disable-sync')
    prog_args.append('--metrics-recording-only')
    prog_args.append('--disable-default-apps')
    prog_args.append('--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows')
    prog_args.append('--disable-renderer-backgrounding')
    prog_args.append('--disable-background-timer-throttling')
    prog_args.append('--disable-ipc-flooding-protection')
    prog_args.append('--password-store=basic')
    prog_args.append('--force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/')
    prog_args.append('--use-mock-keychain')
    prog_args.append('--enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0,CustomElementsV0,HTMLImports') # This is done by WITS, so we do it as well
    prog_args.append('--user-data-dir={0}'.format(tempfile.TemporaryDirectory().name))   # To open a new window, # Create a temporary directory for the dummy chrome profile
    prog_args.append('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
    prog_args.append('http://localhost:{0}{1}'.format(debugport,devUrl))
    subprocess.run(prog_args)

  finally:
    print("Done")

# If the script file is called by itself then execute the main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
  runMain()
```